Spark JDBC Postgres with partitionColumn yields duplicate and missing rows
I am reading from my POSTGRES table using Spark JDBC with 10 connections, and using RNO as the partition column with boundaries ranging from 0 to the number of rows in the table.
This table is dynamic and increases every second.
The first step is to count the rows, and then I use this value to set the upperBound.
The issue we are facing is that we always get duplicate rows, or there are missing rows that I expect to see but cannot find.
val rows = calcCountRows(table)
val numPartitions = math.min(partitions, rows)

spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .options(database.connectionDetails())
  .option("fetchsize", 100)
  .option("dbtable",
    s"""
       |(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS RNO, subQuery.* from $table subQuery) as "$table"
       |""".stripMargin)
  .option("partitionColumn", "RNO")
  .option("lowerBound", 0)
  .option("upperBound", rows)
  .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
  .load()

When I fetch data from the DataFrame, I sometimes see duplicate entries, and if I try to read again, I see different duplicate entries or even missing entries.
How can I handle this issue?

Possible there OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - undefined row ordering. Try use unique column for ordering.

RNO is unique. @ValNik

Each connection recreates the rno column?
